# How to generalize (throwing) function signature in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, closures

I'm currently working on some generic wrapper which takes a closure "knowing" how to create an instance `T` of any type lazily. The goal is to inject this wrapper into other objects which shouldn't have any knowledge about how to actually create `T` since this can by dynamic at runtime and to make sure that once the instance is created it will be reused instead of recreated.

```
class LazyInstance<T> {

    let makeInstance: () -> T
    let instanceIfCached: () -> T?

    init(makeInstance: @escaping () -> T) {

         var instance = T?.none

         self.instanceIfCached = {

            instance
         }

         self.makeInstance = {

            if let instance = instance {

                return instance
            }

            let newInstance = makeInstance()
            instance = newInstance

            return newInstance
         }
     }
 }

class LazyThrowingInstance<T> {

    let makeInstance: () throws -> T
    let instanceIfCached: () -> T?

    init(makeInstance: @escaping () throws -> T) {

         var instance = T?.none

         self.instanceIfCached = {

            instance
         }

         self.makeInstance = {

            if let instance = instance {

                return instance
            }

            let newInstance = try makeInstance()
            instance = newInstance

            return newInstance
         }
     }
 }
```

In some cases it's necessary that my closure `throw`s if an instance cannot be guaranteed to be created. My question is: is there a way to generalize "default" and throwing closures by an additional generic or any other elegant way which affects the injected closure on the one hand side and is also reflected by the `makeInstance` property on the other hand side?

Comment: Can you show more code to illustrate the problem that you are having? The code you posted seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Have you considered using an optional init? Like `init?`. The `makeInstance` closure would return an optional as well. Rather than throw, just return `nil` if there's an issue. Not sure if this will work for you; just a thought.

Comment: I added code for the throwing closure approach. There are cases in which an instance can be created in any case e.g. where just `.init()` is called inside the closure. In these cases I'd like to avoid fiddling with `Optional`s. So I am searching for an abstraction to handle both cases.